# Conditional method chaining in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, method-chaining

Is there a simple general way to make a method conditional to an if-statement when using method chaining with pandas?

Mock example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['one', 'two'], 'B':['one', 'two']})

change_to_numeric = False

df = (df
    .query("A == 'one'")
    .replace('one', 1)         # <-- Execute this row only "if change_to_numeric == True"
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['one', 'two'], 'B':['one', 'two']})

change_to_numeric = False

df = (df
    .query("A == 'one'")
    .pipe(lambda d: d.replace('one', 1) if change_to_numeric else d)
)
```

output for `change_to_numeric = False`:

```
     A    B
0  one  one
```

output for `change_to_numeric = True`:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
```